# Windows utility to visualize progress

Tags: windows

I am searching for utility which creates some auxiliary window to vizualize progress.

Expectations:

1. Gives user information on currently pending long operation, e.g. `Record 1234 of 5000 (24.6%)` either in always-on-top window or on the taskbar in form of number or small progress bar.
2. Life cycle updatable from the command line, like

   - `visutil start 0 5000 "Processing 1"`
   - `visutil update 1234 5000 "Processing 1"`
   - `visutil end 5000 5000 "Processing 1 FINISHED"`